# Much of an impact

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

She was too drunk for it to have much of an impact on her.

1. Is "much of" natural in examples like this? Or would it only be natural if the sentence was something like: She was so drunk that it didn't have much of an impact on her.
2. Would "much of an impact" as used in my example often mean that it had no impact on her at all?

Answer (score 1):

Both of those expressions could be used, as could this one:
She was drunk **enough** that it didn't have much impact on her.

The expression "not much" means the impact was not great, and that includes the possibility that it had no impact on her at all, though it doesn't state that.

You cant conclude that it "often" means "no impact". It just doesn't say that.